# React test state change after timeout

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

say I have a Card element that flips when clicked upon. After 2 seconds, it must automatically flip back. In CSS terms, after clicking, the transform style is set to **rotateY(180deg)**, after 2 seconds it should becom **Initial**

I want to write unit tests for this back-flip (currently the test passes even though I expect the transform prop to equal initial):

```
it( 'flips', () => {
        const testedCard = shallow( <Card /> )
        testedCard.setState( { faceUp: true } )

        setTimeout(
            () => {
                const cardFlipper = testedCard.node.props.children
                expect( cardFlipper.props.transform ).to.equal( 'initdasddaial' )
            },
            2500
        );
    } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mocha` or `jasmine`, you can pass a `done` callback in the `it`:

```
it( 'flips', (done) => {
        const testedCard = shallow( <Card /> )
        testedCard.setState( { faceUp: true } )

        setTimeout(
            () => {
                const cardFlipper = testedCard.node.props.children
                expect( cardFlipper.props.transform ).to.equal( 'initdasddaial' )
                done();
            },
            2500
        );
    } )
```

However, depending on your test runner (settings), the `done` timeout might occur *before* 2500 mills.  You might have to configure a different timeout value.

As a side note, unit tests based on timing are not usually a good idea.  Consider designing the component so that you can test more deterministically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Trying to get it to work. I have jasmine 2.5 installed. Anytime I run this even with setTimeout( ( done ) => { ... }, 1  ), the async callback is not invoked before jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is reached.

Comment: For me it worked only once I installed jasmine.clock + used jasmine.clock().tick(2000) after the timeout. I definitely need to gain experience with proper component design, but this really exceeds the space we have in this question. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found a solution!  :)